# PHP array declaration issue

Tags: php, arrays, declaration

```
$info = array(
        "First_Names" => "John",
        "Last_Names" => "Smith",
        "Gender" => "Male",
    );

array_push($info["First_Names"], "$fname");

print_r ($info);
```

I started learning PHP through a high school class. I'm not exactly knowledgeable nor do I pay attention much, but I'm completely stuck on this;

What I'm trying to do is get the variable $fname which is defined by the user (Jack, James, Shelly, etc) to be pushed into the array First_Names which is inside the array of $info. I'm not sure where it's going wrong, but PHP is not declaring $info as an array (I think, it states "Warning: array_push() [function.array-push]: First argument should be an array in /home/a4938424/public_html/process.php on line 22". If I print out the array it will show up the default names and gender,and if I echo out the $fname variable it shows up properly.)

I've consulted two different people and neither of their suggestions worked, now I'm stumped completely and everyone is out of suggestions. Does anyone see what's going on with it? Thanks for any responses, please be aware that I barely know any PHP.

Comment: You also have a spare comma in the array declaration after the last entry (Gender, Male) which you should get rid of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$info['First_Names']` is not an array, it is a string (`"John"`). If you define it as an array, it might work ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the elements of your array to be arrays, you have to declare them as such:

```
$info = array(
        "First_Names" => array("John"),
        "Last_Names" => array("Smith"),
        "Gender" => array("Male"),
    );
```

However, IMHO this is poor design. Instead of an associative array whose values are indexed arrays, invert it to an indexed array whose elements are associative arrays.

```
$info = array(array('First_Name' => 'John',
                    'Last_Name' => 'Smith',
                    'Gender' => 'Male')
             );
```

This allows you to treat each person as a single element, instead of having to loop over all the sub-arrays in parallel. To add another person to the array, you do:

```
$info[] = array('First_Name' => $fname, 'Last_Name' => $lname, 'Gender' => $gender);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$info['First_Names']` isn't an array.  If you are trying to push the name into `$info` you will need to create an array with your info and then push it (creating a multidimensional array in the process).

```
$a = array("First_Names" => $fname);
array_push($info, $a);
```

If you are trying to overwrite the information in `['First_Name']` then simply access it by it's key.

```
$info['First_Name'] = $fname;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare an array inside the array. Here is an example:

```
<?php
$fnames = array("John","Adam");
$lnames = array("Smith","Kowalski");
$gender = array("Male","Male");

$info = array(
            "First_Names" => $fnames,
            "Last_Names" => $lnames,
            "Gender" => $gender
        );

$new_name = "New John";

array_push($info["First_Names"],$new_name);

var_dump($info);
?>
```

Cheers :)